# How do i disable multiple elements in wpf based on combo box selection?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface

I need to disable a `ComboBox` and a `Label` based on another `ComboBox` selection.

I have the following code to disable combo-box but additionally i need to disable the label with the combo box.

**XAML**

```
<Label  Style="{StaticResource LabelTitle}"   Content="F"  x:Name="Label_FType" Margin="25.087,24.592,-94.145,7.6" d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height"  />
<ComboBox x:Name="Combo_F_Type" Style="{StaticResource ComboBox}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Margin="46.145,29.692,0,12.5" Grid.Column="1" 
          Width="226.199" HorizontalAlignment="Left" d:LayoutOverrides="Height">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Select Type" IsSelected="True" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="F1" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="F2" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="F3" />
</ComboBox> 

<Label Style="{StaticResource LabelTitle}" Content="S" x:Name="Label_SType" Margin="25.087,3.1,-94.145,29.092" d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height" Grid.Row="1" />
<ComboBox Style="{StaticResource EnableSType}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Margin="46.145,8.2,0,33.992" Grid.Column="1" Width="226.199"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" d:LayoutOverrides="Height" Grid.Row="1" >
   <ComboBoxItem Content="Select Type" IsSelected="True" />
   <ComboBoxItem Content="S1" />
   <ComboBoxItem Content="S2" />
   <ComboBoxItem Content="S3" />
   <ComboBoxItem Content="S4" />
</ComboBox>
```

**XAML STYLE**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" x:Key="EnableSType">
    <Setter  Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Combo_FType, Path=SelectedIndex}" Value="3">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Select an answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind the Labels IsEnabled property to the IsEnabled property of the ComboBox.

```
<Label IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=Combo_S_Type, Path=IsEnabled}" Style="{StaticResource LabelTitle}"   Content="S" x:Name="Label_SType" Margin="25.087,3.1,-94.145,29.092" d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height" Grid.Row="1"  />
       <ComboBox x:Name="Combo_S_Type" Style="{StaticResource EnableSType}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Margin="46.145,8.2,0,33.992" Grid.Column="1" Width="226.199" HorizontalAlignment="Left" d:LayoutOverrides="Height" Grid.Row="1" >
           <ComboBoxItem Content="Select Type" IsSelected="True" />
           <ComboBoxItem Content="S1" />
           <ComboBoxItem Content="S2" />
           <ComboBoxItem Content="S3" />
           <ComboBoxItem Content="S4" />
      </ComboBox>
```

Comment: Thank You. Worked Well for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new style that inherit the base label style `LabelTitle` it should be something like this

#### XAML STYLE

```
<Style x:Key="EnableSTypeLabel" BasedOn="{StaticResource LabelTitle}" TargetType="Label">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=Combo_FType, Path=SelectedIndex}" Value="3">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

#### XAML

```
<Label Style="{StaticResource EnableSTypeLabel}" Content="S" x:Name="Label_SType" Margin="25.087,3.1,-94.145,29.092" d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height" Grid.Row="1"  />
```

Comment: Thank You. Worked Well for me.